# File not found in MySQL data directory

Tags: mysql

I am trying to load an XML file into a table on my localhost MySQL server. Per MySQL 5.6 refman page I have my file loaded in the Data directory however I keep getting the error that my file is not found.  I executed the **SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_Name LIKE "%dir"** command and found where my data dictionary is located (C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\Data) and it's where I put my xml file but still get the same error:

```
mysql> USE test
Database changed
mysql> LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'testXML.xml'
  -> INTO TABLE testxml
  -> ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<Data>';
ERROR 2 (HY000): File 'testXML.xml' not found (Errcode: 2 - No such file
or directory)
```

Any suggestions/direction would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember having such a problem once and the problem was the spaces in the path name.

If really the file is at the right place and a file not found occur, I would highly suspect that the folder name 'MySQL Server 5.6' is the problem. You can validate this easily, put the file in another folder instead of the data dir and try adding/removing spaces to the folder name and see if it works.

An other possibility is that your folder is located in an Admin directory and that you don't have right to access.

Comment: This is a windows box so that is a possibility I guess.  I'll give that a try.  I appreciate your help and response.

Comment: Hey Jean-Francois, I changed the directory and it finally worked. Thanks for your help.